# wxPython: Why does modeless, non modal dialog stay on top of parent window?

Tags: dialog, wxpython, modeless

I want to open a dialog **modeless with** **Show()**. After opening I can click on the parent window so the dialog opened successfully modeless.
The problem I have is that the modeless dialog always stays on top of the parent window. I want the parent to get on top when I click on it.

It doesn't matter wether I give the dialog a parent window or not. I test for the **wx.STAY_ON_TOP style which is False** for the dialog.

With simple code below (copied and modified from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wxpython/wx_dialog_class.htm) I'm having the same problem.

How can I get a modeless dialog that can get behind the parent window?

```
import wx

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class MyDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(250, 150))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.btn = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_OK, label="ok", size=(50, 20), pos=(75, 50))

        style = self.GetWindowStyle()
        if style & wx.STAY_ON_TOP:
            print('STAY_ON_TOP = True')
        else:
            print('STAY_ON_TOP = False')

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Mywin(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Mywin, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(300, 300))
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        btn1 = wx.Button(panel, label="Modal Dialog", pos=(20, 10))
        btn2 = wx.Button(panel, label="Modeless Dialog Parent", pos=(20, 40))
        btn3 = wx.Button(panel, label="Modeless Dialog Parentless", pos=(20, 70))

        btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnModal)
        btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnModelessParent)
        btn3.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnModelessParentless)
        self.Show(True)

    def OnModal(self, event):
        MyDialog(self, "Dialog").ShowModal()

    def OnModelessParent(self, event):
        dlg = MyDialog(self, "Dialog").Show()

    def OnModelessParentless(self, event):
        dlg = MyDialog(None, "Dialog").Show()

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ex = wx.App()
Mywin(None, 'Modal / Modeless')
ex.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the style `wx.DIALOG_NO_PARENT` to your dialog's constructor allows the dialogs to float behind the frame. Ex:

```
import wx


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class MyDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(250, 150),
                                       style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE | wx.DIALOG_NO_PARENT)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.btn = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_OK, label="ok", size=(50, 20), pos=(75, 50))

        style = self.GetWindowStyle()
        if style & wx.STAY_ON_TOP:
            print('STAY_ON_TOP = True')
        else:
            print('STAY_ON_TOP = False')


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Mywin(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Mywin, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(300, 300))
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        btn1 = wx.Button(panel, label="Modal Dialog", pos=(20, 10))
        btn2 = wx.Button(panel, label="Modeless Dialog Parent", pos=(20, 40))
        btn3 = wx.Button(panel, label="Modeless Dialog Parentless", pos=(20, 70))

        btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnModal)
        btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnModelessParent)
        btn3.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnModelessParentless)
        self.Show(True)

    def OnModal(self, event):
        MyDialog(self, "Dialog").ShowModal()

    def OnModelessParent(self, event):
        MyDialog(self, "Dialog").Show()

    def OnModelessParentless(self, event):
        MyDialog(None, "Dialog").Show()


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ex = wx.App()
Mywin(None, 'Modal / Modeless')
ex.MainLoop()
```

I removed the variable assignment `dlg =` on your 2 modeless event handlers because `Show()` returns `True` not the dialog instance.

It should also be noted that dialogs aren't automatically destroyed and you must call `Destroy()` manually to release their memory when you're done with them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's working great now. You're right about the sloppy Show() and Destroy().